# connection failed: Connection refused Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

Tags: python, django, gcloud, sqlconnection

i am getting an error connecting to sql cloud during deployment to google cloud,
in my sql cloud, IP public is **34.66.xx.xxx**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NC0i3.png) but when I run code  `./cloud-sql-proxy <connection_name>` then feedback:

```
2024/03/05 22:53:02 Authorizing with Application Default Credentials
2024/03/05 22:53:03 [django-ecommerce-416314:us-central1:django-ecommerce-instance] Listening on 127.0.0.1:5432
2024/03/05 22:53:03 The proxy has started successfully and is ready for new connections!
```

in my setting code django setting, I config database

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'shopeedb',
        'USER': 'admin',
        'PASSWORD': 'admin',
        'HOST': '34.66.xx.xxx',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

more detail: I can run server on UI server but when LOGIN, REGISTER,... related with DB it not active.
What need I do now? Thanks!

I tried change config

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'shopeedb',
        'USER': 'admin',
        'PASSWORD': 'admin',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

results returned: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y8WZI.jpg)
but when I run with config

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'shopeedb',
        'USER': 'admin',
        'PASSWORD': 'admin',
        'HOST': '34.66.xx.xxx',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

results returned: **502 bad gate way Nginx**